# Calling an Angular Factory recursively gives a circular dependency error

Tags: angularjs, recursion, dependency-injection, factory

I have an application with multithreaded comments, and I'm trying to use an Angular factory to create objects with all the necessary functions and properties recursively, since of course, a comment can have many replies, each of which can have more replies...

Below is my factory representing a comment:

```
app.factory("Comment", ["commentHttpService", "Comment", function(commentHttpService, Comment) {
    return function(comment) {
        var self = comment;

        // lots of other properties and methods here

        self.children = self.children.map(function(reply) {
            return new Comment(reply);
        });

        return self;
    }
}]);
```

Of course, this doesn't work since I'm injecting `Comment` into itself.

How can I resolve this and still accomplish my original goal?

Comment: `commentHttpService` simply makes HTTP requests to my server and shouldn't be relevant for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app.factory("Comment", ["commentHttpService", function(commentHttpService) {
    function Comment(comment) {
        var self = comment;

        // lots of other properties and methods here

        self.children = self.children.map(function(reply) {
            return new Comment(reply);
        });
    }

    return Comment;
}]);
```

Comment: I refuse to believe it is this simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another way of achieving what you want could be creating a factory that lets yu create a Comment instance which has all its apis attached to it:

```
    app.factory("CommentFactory", function() {
        function Comment(comment) {
            this.message = comment;
            this.replies = [];


            this.getMessage = function() {
              return this.message;
            }

            this.addReply = function(reply) {
              var replyComment = new Comment(reply);
              this.replies.push(replyComment);
              return replyComment;
            }

            this.getReplies = function() {
              return replies;
            }
        }

        return {
          createComment: function(message) {
            return new Comment(message);
          }
        }
    });
```

Here is a small plunk:
http://plnkr.co/edit/BmfCm9?p=preview

You can create comments using factory and add replies to comments which are also instances of Comments.